# Drawing a panel figure of pedigrees using drawPedigree in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot multiple pedigrees into a single figure. I'd have thought that the following produces a 1 x 2 panel figure with two (in this case, identical) pedigrees when using the [`drawPedigree`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pedantics/versions/1.5/topics/drawPedigree) function, because I have specified `par(mfrow = c(1,2))`, but that just gives a single pedigree. Perhaps the `drawPedigree` function produces something that is not handled in the same way as a plot would be. How can I force R to produce two pedigrees side-by-side within a single PNG file?

```
library("pedantics")
data(gryphons)
ped1 <- fixPedigree(gryphons[,1:3])
ped2 <- ped1
png("C:\\Users\\ell\\Dropbox\\temp.png", width = 360, height = 180, units = "mm", res = 1000)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
drawPedigree(ped1)
drawPedigree(ped2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: It seems that somthing is resetting the par in the function `drawPedigree`. Couldn't find it through. The data graph is so dense that it's difficult to split in half anyway. In the worst case imagemagick might do the job.